# Retrieve those contacts from phonebook that has Social account

Tags: android, android-contacts

i have retrive contacts from phonebook that has any social acconut like whatsApp, twitter, google+ etc. Is there any way to get whatsapp and another social contact from local phonebook itself?

i have try following code to get all contacts

```
Cursor phone = getContentResolver().query(
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
        null, null);
phone.moveToFirst();
while (phone.moveToNext()) {

    String name = phone
            .getString(phone
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    String phoneNumber = phone
            .getString(phone
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name:"+name+"Number:"+phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    contactArray.add(new GetSetContact(name, phoneNumber));

}
phone.close();
```

but from this code i will only get all contact not get the only those contact which has a social account like whatsapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put package name in query

```
cursor7 = getContentResolver().query(
                android.provider.ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, "account_type='package name'", null,
                null);
```